# Redirect to an angular page url from Springboot rest api

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, cors

I have been searching on how to redirect to an angular page from Spring boot api.
I tried many ways but none has worked.

- Front end: (angular) http://localhost:4200
- Back end: (springboot) http://localhost:80

```
          Login Page
           |     |
          /       \
    admin page   regular page
```

1. I added proxy.conf.json and added the api url (did not work) and not advisable for a production (I read here in stackoverflow)
2. Added RedirectView and pass the url if it is admin page or regular page but I am having a CORS error **request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."**

What am I missing? Please help.

My Cors Configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200)
                        .allowedHeaders("*")
                        .maxAge(1800);


            }
        };
    }
```

My Endpoint:

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/login")
    public RedirectView authenticate(@RequestBody RequestDTO request) {

        // some codes here for authResponse


        if (null != authResponse) {
            if (authResponse.isAdmin()) {
                 url = "/admin-profile";
            } else {
               url =  "/regular-profile";

            }
        }

     String appUrl = host + url;
     return RedirectView(appUrl);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly redirect an API request to change the browser's location. If it were not for your CORS errors, you'd just be getting nonsense back at the UI where you called the API.

What you need to do is, instead of redirecting from the back-end, send some sort of error to from the back-end to the front-end in response to the API request, containing the new URL, and have an error handler in the front-end that changes the browser's location to the URL I'm the custom error.

Comment: Hi sir @GreyBeardedGeek, thanks for the advise. I modified my codes and I am now passing the URL from the backend to front end. Thanks